# Gradient Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xaml

Estou fazendo as telas de um app Xamarin com XAML, e queria colocar um background gradient é possível ?
Por enquanto o código é esse:

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar um componente pronto:
Git: [XFGloss: Xamarin.Forms UI Enhancements](https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss)
Nuget: [XFGloss for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ansuria.XFGloss/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xfg="clr-namespace:XFGloss;assembly=XFGloss"
             x:Class="XFGlossSample.Views.AboutPage"
             Title="XFGloss Sample App" Padding="10">

    <xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
        <xfg:Gradient Rotation="150">
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="White" StepPercentage="0" />
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="White" StepPercentage=".5" />
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#ccd9ff" StepPercentage="1" />
        </xfg:Gradient>
    </xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]